# Unable to Debug XNA Game1 Class - VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, monogame

As the title states, I am unable to debug my `Game1` class only. If I place a breakpoint in `Game1` and start debugging, I get the message

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version.
```

I have not made any recent changes to this file. If I place a breakpoint in a different class, it works just fine.

I have:

- Manually deleted the PDB files
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution
- Closed and reopened the solution
- Restarted my computer

Despite not making any changes, the debugger thinks my code file has changed and won't hit any breakpoints. I can turn off the "require code to be the same" option, but I'd rather not do this.

**Edit:** It's also worth noting that this was working before. I've been working on this particular solution for about a month, and this just started this morning. No changes were made to the file after the last successful debug.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: What configuration are you building for? Check to make sure the problem project is being built as part of it.

Comment: @Juan Looks like that's it ... unsure what changed but that project wasn't being built! If you'd like to make it an answer, it's yours.

Comment: Awesome. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the problem project is being built as part of the current Build configuration. :-)